# How to enable SQL trace for AWS Oracle RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, database, oracle, rds

To enable sql trace under Oracle you would typically run the following via sqlplus after login:

ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE=TRUE

On Oracle 19 RDS this results in the following:

*Error report -
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges*

How is the sql trace mechanism enabled under AWS RDS?